# Odd error with regular expression in grep

Tags: grep

I'm running the following command:

```
cat something | egrep "(abc|def)$"
```

On a server running Linux.

The same OS with kernel 2.6.18 gives the correct answer, while with 2.6.19 I get:

```
Illegal variable name.
```

Apparently the $ sign is causing the error, but the question is why is it behaving differently across kernels?

Comment: Is the version of grep the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Are you using the same type of shell on both machines?

2) Have you tried using single quotes, so that the shell doesn't try to interpret the dollar sign as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Its more likely this is an issue with the shell you're running.  First, the quotes; when using single quotes, variables won't be replaced in the outcoming string.  I.e.,

```
% VAR="hello"
% echo "$VAR world!"
hello world!
% eco '$VAR world!'
$VAR world!
```

In your case, its literally trying to execute `$`, but `$` is not a valid variable name.  If you use single quotes, the shell won't allow the dollar sign to be replaced.